# Elements of Angular stop to respond after a time

Tags: angularjs, frontend

Hy every one!
I'm using in this project Angular 1.6.5 because my workteam think is better.

But I found an error with angular elements. In all forms of my app They stop the behaviour after a time. That is, it doesn't save date when i click in button save, ore delete. But when i refresh the page the elements start responds again. Any one have idea why?

In the project we are using a library to control style css. the problem may be there?

here is one piece of my html code

```
<div class="col-4-1">
        <p class="link"><a class="btn-pri" href ng-click="savePartner()" ng-if="enableSaveBtn">Save</a></p>
        <p class="link"><a class="btn-pri remove-link btn-red-50" href ng-click="delPartner()" ng-if="enableDelBtn">Erase</a></p>
</div>
```

pice controller code:

```
$scope.addLabelToPartner = function() {
    $scope.partner.LabelList = $scope.partner.mcnList || [];
    $scope.partner.LabelList.push($scope.partner.code);
    $scope.partner.code = "";
};

$scope.delLabelFromPartner = function(idx) {
    $scope.partner.LabelList.splice(idx, 1);
};

$scope.savePartner = function() {
    $scope.saveErr = false;
    WebService.createPartner($scope.partner).then(
        function(response) {
            common.widget.overlay.hide("overlayPartnerForm");
            $scope.fetchAllPartners();
        },
        function(error) {
            $scope.saveErr = true;
        }
    );
};

$scope.delPartner = function() {
    $scope.saveErr = false;
    WebService.deletePartner($scope.partner._id).then(
        function(response) {
            common.widget.overlay.hide("overlayPartnerForm");
            $scope.fetchAllPartners();
        },
        function(error) {
            $scope.saveErr = true;
        }
    );
};
```

Comment: Give us the controller code, maybe you have a problem with your functions inside

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be… **Complete** – Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I don't think have relations whit the controller because it works normally. is just in this situation, when page pass a few time without interaction that this problem occurs. Any way i past the code involved.